# Changing tableview height in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change tableview when keyboard appears to screen in swift. Because if I don't update the height, bottom messages hides under the keyboard. Here screenshots:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

You can see in the screenshots, my tableview still under the keyboard. I used following code and didn't work.

```
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
        self.tableView.frame.size.height=self.tableView.frame.size.height-keyboardFrame.size.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
            self.bottomCons.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height //This line is for textbox and button. Unrelated with tableview.
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
}
```

Why tableview height is not changing? How can I fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't be changing the table's `frame` for this. Change its `contentInset` instead.

Comment: Could you explain more?

Comment: You can find more information about contentInset [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentInset). All you have to do is animate `contentInset.bottom` to the keyboard's height when you show it. (possibly adjusting `contentOffset` as well as necessary.

Comment: I tried it manually for see how it works before the code. I think i am doing something wrong. Can you check this? http://prntscr.com/7iz4lt Scroll bar is on the correct position but cells are not.

Comment: That's only setting the insets for the scroll indicator, not the table view itself. If I recall correctly, a table's content insets have to be set programmatically.

Comment: Ok, last question: What is the default contentInset value?

Comment: The default inset is 0.  But I might argue that you shouldn't be changing either, instead you should be using autolayout, and changing the bottom-most constraint when the keyboard animates on/off.  Moreover, you're making the effort to set the height based on the keyboard's height... why not go ahead and grab the animation duration out of that exact same dictionary?